# How to unload a lisp file in CLisp REPL?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Am able to load and call the functions but I would like to 
reload the file after making some corrections.

Cant find either an unload or reload function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `load` again.

Answer (score 11):

Unloading is not really possible. It is for example possible to delete a package and thus remove its definitions. But other references to a symbol of that package might still exist.

The typical way to deal with that is to [load](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm#load) a file again, as Vijay Mathew mentioned.

It might be helpful that the file loaded is written in such a way that reloading is possible.

A few remarks on reloading:

- functions/macros will be replaced with the new definition.
- functions/macros in existing code may not be replaced due to inlining/macro expansion.
- CLOS classes will be updated, its instances will be lazily updated.
- Structure definitions will be updated, existing structure instances will not be updated.
- DEFVAR replaces a value if one doesn't exist. DEFPARAMETER always replaces a value.

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but here we go. It’s worth mentioning that any functions/macros/etc. you may have deleted from the file will still hang around, polluting the image and possibly causing behaviour that you would not see in a completely clean build.